# Ajax on Rails How to use Ajax append method for render HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am not an English speaker.I ask of your understanding.sorry

**/app/views/sale/index.html.erb**
I want to do ajax here

```
<div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:5px;" id=reply_preview>

      <%= render 'sale/billpreview'%>

</div>
```

this is button for sending data

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-defalut reply_sale" value="<%= m.id %>" name="menuid"
```

script

```
<script>
$(".reply_sale").click(function(){

    send_value=this.value;

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/sale/billpreview",
    data: { menuid : send_value },
    dataType : 'json'
  })
  .done(function() {
  $( "#reply_preview" ).append( "<%= render 'sale/billpreview'%>");// <-- error point
  });

 });
</script>
```

here is error point

```
$( "#reply_preview" ).append( "<%= render 'sale/billpreview'%>");// <-- error point
```

What do i type here?

**/app/views/sale/_billpreview.erb**

```
<div style="background-color:white; height:410px;">
  <div style="padding:15px;">
    <div style="color:black">
      <h4>order list</h4>
      <div>=================================</div>
      <div style="height:250px; margin-left:1px; margin-right:1px;">
        <div class="row" style="font-size:14px; height:200px;">
          <% @total_price = 0 %>
          <% if current_user.store.billopen %>
            <% if @billshow.present? %>
              <% @billshow.salesmenu.each do |m|%>

                <span class="col-lg-4"><%= m.menu.name %></span>
                <span class="col-lg-4"><%= m.menu.price * m.qty %></span>
                <span class="col-lg-4">
                  <form action="/sale/qty_plus" method = "post">
                    <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" name = "qty" value ="<%=m.id%>"> </button>
                  </form>
                  <span><%= m.qty %></span>
                  <form action="/sale/qty_minus" method = "post">
                    <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" name ="qty" value ="<%=m.id%>"> </button>
                  </form>
                </span>
                <% @total_price = @total_price + (m.menu.price * m.qty) %>
              <% end %>
            <% else %>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
          <% end %>

        </div>
        <div>--------------------------------------------------------</div>

        <div class="row">
          <span class="col-lg-4">total price</span>
          <span class="col-lg-8" style="text-align:right"><%= @total_price %> </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>=================================</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">

      <form class="col-lg-4" action="/sale/billfinish" method = "post">
        <button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="/sale/billfinish" class="btn btn-default">완료</button>
      </form>
      <form class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='/sale/index'" class="btn btn-default">Initialization</button>
      </form>
      <form class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='/home/index'" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**/app/controllers/home_controller.rb**

```
def billpreview

    if current_user.store.billopen

      @salesmenu = Salesmenu.new
      @salesmenu.menu_id = params[:menuid]
      @salesmenu.bill_id = current_user.store.bills.last.id
      @salesmenu.save

      @billshow = current_user.store.bills.last

    else #
      @bill = Bill.new
      @bill.store_id = current_user.store.id #db connect (bill <-> store)
      @bill.workperiod_id = current_user.store.workperiod.last.id #db connect (bill <-> workpeiod)
      @bill.save


      @salesmenu = Salesmenu.new
      @salesmenu.menu_id = params[:menuid]
      @salesmenu.bill_id = @bill.id
      @salesmenu.qty = 1 

      @salesmenu.save

      @billshow = @bill #current_user.store.bills.last
    end

    @temp_store = current_user.store 
    @temp_store.billopen = true
    @temp_store.save 

return head :no_content
    #redirect_to :back
  end
```

also, i don't know what `return head :no_content` mean
i just copy and paste at google.
I'm not too sure if this is right.
Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you should know and will have to learn as you go on:

Rails links come with a built in function to send ajax requests like this:

```
<%= link_to "My ajax request text", post_new(@post), remote: true %>
```

The "remote: true" option sends an ajax request for that link for you to the specified path (in this case a new post).

Your controller receives every request and responds by redirecting or rendering views which refreshes the page. But when you do an ajax request you don't want that. What you want is that your controller responds via Ajax too. Once again, Rails has a built in function to do that:

```
def billpreview
# write all your logic and set instance variables for the objects you want
# @salesmenu
respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end
end
```

respond_to looks at your request and determines if it is an HTML request (no Ajax) or an Ajax request. If it is an Ajax request it responds with a Javascript file, else it responds with an HTML file which is what it does by default.

In your view folder you will need to create a new file now for your javascript file which Rails can send when you do an Ajax request:

```
billpreview.html.erb
billpreview.js.erb
```

billpreview.html.erb is what you have been using until now. billpreview.js.erb is what you will use when you request an Ajax response.

Inside of billpreview.js.erb you can use the same instance variables you used in billpreview.html.erb.

```
#billpreview.js.erb
$('#id_in_your_view').append('<%= j render @salesmenu %>');
```

Usually you will pick an id in your view ($('#id_in_your_view')) to which you can append or prepend your content. You will have to use <%= j render @salesmenu %> not just "render" because you are using javascript. Once you understand the logic behind it, it becomes really easy. Good luck.

I recommend you watch these 2 youtube videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Il7PPhen3o

Comment: thank you very much. Alexander Luna.  I should learn rails helper and link_to method.

Comment: but i don'w know where i place **<%= link_to "My ajax request text", post_new(@post), remote: true %>** . May i exchange with "<div class="col-lg-4" style="padding:5px;" id=reply_preview> <%= render 'sale/billpreview'%> </div> "  and " <%= link_to "My ajax request text", post_new(@post), remote: true %>"??  . And what is @post in your answer? I don't have post DB.   sorry,sir... Afterwards, i will learn rails helper and link.

Comment: @post was just an example. You use <%= link_to "My ajax request text", post_new(@post), remote: true %> instead of your button.